# WPF window different in windows 8.1 and windows 7

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013

I'm working on an application in WPF (C#) that will use a webcam but I'm having issues with the main window.  I am getting my desired look when I run it in windows 7 however when I run it on a windows 8.1 machine it looks different.

This is the desired look (Windows 7)

[image]

This is what it looks like on Windows 8.1 (it doesn't stretch to fill the screen when maximizing)

[image]

Here is my code for the mainwindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:cam="clr-namespace:WebcamControl;assembly=WebcamControl"    
Title="WPF Webcam" Height="664.333" Width="645">
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DevicesListTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>


<Grid Margin="0,0,0,0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <cam:Webcam Name="WebcamCtrl" Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>

    <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal"  Grid.Row="1">
        <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Width="200" VerticalAlignment="Center"
            x:Name="AudioDevicesComboBox" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DevicesListTemplate}" Margin="10,0,10,0"/>
        <ComboBox Height="22" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center"
            x:Name="VideoDevicesComboBox" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DevicesListTemplate}" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="tbScan" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" Margin="0,0,10,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100" KeyDown="tbScan_KeyDown"/>
        <Button Content="Start" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" Margin="0,0,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="78" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

This is the xaml from the webcam user control

```
<UserControl x:Class="Webcam" 
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"              
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"
         MinHeight="100" MinWidth="100"
         mc:Ignorable="d">
<Grid>
    <WindowsFormsHost Name="WinFormsHost" Margin="0" Background="{x:Null}">
        <wf:Panel x:Name="WebcamPanel"/>
    </WindowsFormsHost>
</Grid>
```

I also found this event in the Webcam.dll source code.

```
    Private Sub Webcam_SizeChanged(sender As Object, e As SizeChangedEventArgs) Handles Me.SizeChanged
    If (deviceSource IsNot Nothing) Then
        deviceSource.PreviewWindow.SetSize(New Size(CInt(Me.ActualWidth), CInt(Me.ActualHeight)))
    End If
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I added a border around the "cam:Webcam.." item in the mainwindow and it does stretch so I'm thinking it must be something in the webcam user control that is not allowing it to stretch.

Comment: It would be hard for anyone to provide specific advice without a _minimal_, _complete_ code example. E.g. one that shows the difference in Win7 and Win8 with pure WPF code, not using the web cam library or hardware. That said, have you tried using the `Stretch` property on the user control?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping it in a Viewbox?

Answer (score 1):

There is space between cam:Webcam and Stackpanel control in Main Grid.
So your cam:Webcam is streched (Alignments setups are not necessary, this is the default behavior of Grid)

My oppinion is the problem is WindowsFormsHost or Panel.
I prefer to you to check your layout with a spy, like [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/).
It will help for you to find your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.  I discovered that if I stop the preview and restart it, it expands to full screen (in win 8.1).  In Win7 I don't have to restart.  It's still bothering me that I can't figure it out but at least I can just have an event fire when then window maximizes to restart the preview.

Comment: I edited the original question to show an event that is triggered on size change.  This event is from the source code of the dll I used for the webcam control